# What anti-virus software could be used on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: security, anti-virus, windows-server-2008

My Win2008 R2 server is protected only by Windows Defender. I REALLY doubt its capability. So, what option else do I have?

PS. Win2008 R2 has only 64bit version.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info on why you aren't confident in Defender? Depending on what you are using the server for, it may be just fine.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I want to use it as a web server and also my working machine. I will use it to surf the Internet as well. So any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: As this is written it is too open ended to be able to be answered properly. Answers will be opinion and experience, rather than factual and empirical. Please rephrase your question if you have a more direct and specific request.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of paid products but if you are looking for free look in to FortiClient. There are a few others out there but this will get you started.
http://www.fortinet.com/products/endpoint/